# How to express using integrals the area of the region bounded by $xy=6, y=2, y=6, and x=6$ to find volume of region

Tags: calculus, volume, area

Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region bounded by the above graphs of the equations around the line y=6.

My Attempt
$\int_1^6(6- 6/x)) ^2 dx$

Why would we need two integrals? The region is consistently defined by the curve y=6/x. My teacher wrote two integrals and summed them. She wrote $\int_1^3 (6-6/x))^2dx + \int_3^6 16 dx$

16 comes from $\pi r^2$.

She assumes the second region has a constant radius but that isn't true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $1\le x\le3$, the radius $R=6-6/x$, but for $3\le x\le6$, the radius $R=4$; so

the volume of the solid is given by $\displaystyle V=\int_1^3\pi\big(6-\frac{6}{x}\big)^2dx+\int_3^6\pi(4)^2 dx$.

More simply, using the shell method gives $\displaystyle V=\int_2^62\pi(6-y)\big(6-\frac{6}{y}\big) dy$.

Comment: how is the radius 4? It increases. Can you give me a graph of the region from 3 to 6?

Comment: I think the question could have been stated a little more clearly, but I believe the region that is intended is bounded below by $y=2$, above by $y=6$, on the left by $xy=6$, and on the right by $x=6$.  (There is a region below $y=2$ which is bounded by $xy=6$ and by $x=6$, but the line $y=2$ would not have been included in the problem if this region were meant to be included also.)